# An entry is required or has an invalid value. Please correct and try again on Powerapps

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps

I'm having the error:

`"An entry is required or has an invalid value. Please correct and try again ".`

Due to this error, I'm unable to save my records to share point online. Could you help me how to resolve this error? Unable to figure out since weeks.

Thanks,
MK

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this by turning off the Experimental Feature "Delayed Load".

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any fields on your sharepoint which is required and it is not added in Powerapps. or check the data type of all the fields.

Comment: I checked everything but didn't find any errors with the data types and fields. This error occurs only when certain options are chosen on choice type on both SharePoint online and power Apps